# Requested item is quarantined in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to run the command npx create-react-app under a corporate registry. The problem is that the element sockjs@0.3.18 is not available and therefore it stalls the installation; however, the element sockjs@0.3.17 is. Is there any way I can run that command by specifying it should install a different version of sockjs?.

Answer (score 0):

Using `npm ls sockjs`, I see this is a dependency of `react-scripts@1.1.4` / `webpack-dev-server@2.9.4`

> └─┬ react-scripts@1.1.4
>
> ----└─┬ webpack-dev-server@2.9.4
>
> --------└── sockjs@0.3.18

There's an option in `create-react-app` to use a nonstandard version of `react-scripts`:

> --scripts-version <alternative-package>

This should work:

> npx create-react-app --scripts-version 0.9.5 app

0.9.5 is the latest version that depends on an earlier `sockjs`.

I found this by looking up the `package.json` of `webpack-dev-server` and then `react-scripts` that had appropriately downgraded versions. (I did it manually on GitHub release pages... anyone know a better tool for that?)

Alternative approaches:

- Get the updated sockjs approved in your corporate registry :)
- Assuming the difference between `sockjs@0.3.18` and `sockjs@0.3.17` is immaterial as for as `create-react-app` goes (no guarantees), you could probably `npm install create-react-app`, find the bit in the source code (`node_modules/create-react-app/create-react-app.js`) that downloads `react-scripts`, and hack it to point to your own fork of the latest `react-scripts` with a changed version number for `webpack-dev-server` (1.16.4). Not recommended!